# ActiveMQ never deletes kahadb .log files; no pending messages visible through JSP interface; how to detect culprit?

Tags: java, apache, activemq-classic

we have ActiveMQ 5.7.0 running on CentOS. Around fifty Java programs write to and consume queues, about half from the localhost and the rest scattered across remote clients, most with one consumer per process, but four with 32.

A few days ago, ActiveMQ stopped deleting .log files from data/kahadb. If restarted, ActiveMQ deletes everything from kahadb, and then deletes nothing else during operation.

No pending (i.e. queued but not dequeued) messages are visible through the web interface at [host]:8161/admin/queues.jsp. DLQ is empty and its deletion does not affect the problem. (Also gleaned from the interface: all connections are active and none are slow, there are no subscribers, no bridges, no scheduler.)

Following http://activemq.apache.org/why-do-kahadb-log-files-remain-after-cleanup.html, I have gotten the following:

> | TRACE | Last update: 236:28401525, full gc candidates set: [89, 90,
>   91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100 *<[snip]>*, 236 |
>   org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase | ActiveMQ Journal
>   Checkpoint Worker 2014-09-11 08:50:03,384 | TRACE | gc candidates
>   after first tx:89:10178611, [] |
>   org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase | ActiveMQ Journal
>   Checkpoint Worker 2014-09-11 08:50:03,384 | TRACE | gc candidates: []
>   | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase | ActiveMQ Journal
>   Checkpoint Worker

where db-89.log is the first log file created after ActiveMQ restart, and db-236.log is the newest currently existent file.

There are no other errors or warnings in the ActiveMQ log. Regarding programs using the queues, there are no consistently reported exceptions. My company's programs, on localhost, are releasing transactions, according to their logs. If a third party program is not releasing a transaction, I don't know how to find that out.

Given all this, how can I pinpoint or narrow down the possible cause of the problem? What additional info would be useful?

As an additional constraint, accessing client machines and their programs is a business problem. I have no accounts there and admins are in different countries, which slows down communication. If I must contact them, I'd like to give them all possible information up front.

Many thanks.

Comment: I'd expect to see the destinations holding the logs mentioned in the trace. What are your KahaDB settings?  Does it take time for this to occur or do the files start to build after the restart? Do you have any subscribers using durable topics?  Lastly, is this a stand alone broker or master/slave configuration?

Comment: For posterity: the files build up immediately. No subscribers used durable topics. It's a standalone broker. I'm not sure which kahadb would have been relevant; kahadb ran out of the box with no additional configuration from us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We solved the problem by investigating ActiveMQ source code to understand the fragment:

> gc candidates after first tx:89:10178611

Turns out, 89 is the log file name (db-89.log), and 10178611 the offset in the file. So, we dumped the log file:

```
xxd -g1 db-89.log | less
```

then we did a text search for our offset (converted to hexadecimal). In the dump, there was the human-readable name of the queue with a hanging transaction and the server it came from.

I don't have access to the problematic server or the code, but the admin told me informally that their developers "fixed" the closing of the transaction, whatever the fix might have been. This solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar scenario, and it turned out that the messages were being stuck in the DLQ, which nobody cared to monitor them... :S

Just a tip: check the DLQs!

Re your solution, I tried to do the same, my line is like this:

> 2014-11-19 12:01:33,964 [eckpoint Worker] TRACE MessageDatabase                - gc candidates after tx range:[496:28242122, 496:28242122], [45, 52, 53, 54,...]

So, according to your instructions I opened the db-496.log file with a hex editor (Notepad++ with Hex viewer plugin) and looked for 28242122 (the offset), but it's not in the file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you remember to convert the offset to hexadecimal before searching?